# Order and Least Common Multiple Abelian Question

Tags: proof-verification, abelian-groups, least-common-multiple

\item Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $x, y\in G$ be elements so
that $o(x)=m$ and $o(y)=n$. Show that $o(xy)=\frac{mn}{(m,n)}$.
(Note that this is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$) Is this
true if $G$ is non-abelian? Give an example.

My Solution

Let $r$ be the least common multiple of $m,n$ then $r = zm =yn$ for some integers $y,z$ so then we can write $(ab)^{r} = a^r b^r = a^{(m)z}b^{(n)y}= e^ze^y = e$ Since $(ab)^r =e$ then the order of $ab$ must divide $r$

My question lies in where this fails if $G$ is non-abelian. I know it fails, but what is a good example for this?

Comment: Actually, this can fail even for Abelian groups.  Consider an element and its inverse.  What you give as the order of xy is merely an upper bound (and only in the Abelian case).

Answer (score 1):

take the non-abelian group on two generators, $x$ and $y$ with $x^2 = y^2 = e$. in this case $xy$ generates an infinite cyclic subgroup

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is wrong even in abelian groups. Take $o(x)=2$. We have $o(xx)=1 \neq 2= \frac{2 \cdot 2}{(2,2)}$.

It becomes true, when you require $(m,n)=1$.